# Benford's law not working?

Tags: probability-distributions, random

So I recently came across Benford's law and immediately tried to code it out but the answer I got was rather confusing. I think my code is correct I'm pretty sure it is but the result is just not the one others get. Here's the code:

```
int a;
float[] flag=new float[10];

  for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
  {
    
    a=floor(random(0,99999));
      while(a>=10)
       a/=10;

      flag[a]++;
  }
```

But I get roughly the same *flag[k]* (around 1100) but according to Benford's law that should not be the case.

I think it is because my upper limit is set so I tried modifying my code as follows :

```
int a;
float p,q,r;
float[] flag=new float[10];

  for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
  {
    r=random(0,99999)
    q=random(0,r);
    p=random(0,q);
    a=floor(random(0,p));
      while(a>=10)
       a/=10;

      flag[a]++;
  }
```

And this gives really satisfactory results, the problem is that this creates a very different type of distribution, it's certainly not random, so the problem I'm running into is that: is this how Benford's law work? Since we don't know the "Cutoff" it makes *1s* significantly more likely than *9s* and other numbers, Since they would require the "Cutoff" to be high which reduces the probability of them occuring in a random "Cutoff" scenario?

Comment: What do you mean by "it's certainly not random"?

Comment: @ChrisCulter because it's more likely to be a lower number than let's say 99999 for example which is highly unlikely

Comment: Okay, that's saying it's certainly not *uniformly* random.

Comment: Please read the description of the tag 'distribution-theory'.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3904913/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/132164/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: @D.W. I posted it CS first but then someone said it's more so mathematical rather than computational so I posted it in maths.

Comment: If you post it on the wrong site, please delete the original copy before posting elsewhere.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Benford's law does not apply to data with a uniform distribution, be it continuous or discrete. It applies to data whose logarithms' fractional parts have a continuous uniform distribution.

Comment: I was thinking the same but I've seen people use it for population of countries and such, also this doesn't explain why it magically appears in case of 2and code, Can you link some study material on this topic please?

Comment: @Avi "2and code"? Wikipedia gives several explanations of the law's applicability, [the last](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law#Scale_invariance) in terms of scale invariance being perhaps the most accessible. To take populations as an example, imagine countries where everyone lives in one of many villages, each of 200 people. You'd *a priori* expect the first digit's distribution across nations to be the same for person counts as for village counts. Ditto for if the villages had 300 people etc.

Comment: Second code* the one where I made the upper limit of the random number generator random too(I did it several times till I got about 2-3% of what's expected of Benford's law).

Comment: @Avi Oh, I can explain that effect. The first code's values' images under $-\ln x$ are exponentially distributed. Your second code trims the left-hand tail of this distribution to get an approximately flat result later.